# Adding a slidedown transition dropdown menus

Tags: html, css

what would I need to add to the CSS stylesheet to ensure that:

1. There is a small delay in the menu dropping down when the mouse is
   hovered over the primary menu, &
2. The menu slides downwards when hovered over, & then upwards to
   disappear when the mouse stops hovering over a primary menu item?

Here is what I have so far;

```css
#nav{
  background-color:#0D0155;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
#navWrapper{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#nav ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0px;
}
#nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
#nav ul li a{
  font-size:14px;
  color:white;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
  background-color:#DFD0DC;
}
#nav ul li a,visited{
  padding:15px;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
  display:inline-block;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  z-index:999;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:10px;
  border-color:#DFD0DC;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:left;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  -webkit-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
  transition:height 200ms ease-in;

}
#nav ul li:hover ul input{
  width:100%;
  /*height:32px;*/
  border-style:solid;
  padding:7px 5px 7px 25px;
  border-color:grey;
  border-width:2px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  color:black;
  position:relative;

}
#nav ul li:hover ul input placeholder{
  color:black !important;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul a{
  padding:5px;
  padding-left:0px;
  margin:0px;
  float:none;
  color:#0045BF;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:red;
}
#nav ul ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav ul li:hover > a{
  background-color:#DFD0DC;
  color: #0D0155;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="nav">
  <div id="navWrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a style="background-color:#555454;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <!--<li><a class="search-dropdown-div-click" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>-->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Our services</strong></a>
        <ul>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">ISA Accounts</div>
              <a href="#">Browse our ISA accounts</a>
              <a href="#">Junior ISA Accounts</a>
              <a href="#">Current Interest Rates</a>
              <a href="#">ISA Costs & Charges</a>
              <a href="#"><strong>Investor Information</strong><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Currency Services</div>
              <a href="#">Curerncy trading</a>
              <a href="#">Spread betting</a>
              <a href="#">Currency Spreads</a>
              <a href="#">Trading Commissions</a>
              <a href="#">Investor Information<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Pension Services<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Drawdowns</a>
              <a href="#">Annuities</a>
              <a href="#"><b>Browse our pension funds</b><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><b>Investor Information<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></b></a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Share dealing<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Trading Costs</a>
              <a href="#">Assets</a>
              <a href="#">FTSE 100</a>
              <a href="#">FTSE 250</a>
              <a href="#">FTSE 350</a>
              <a href="#"><b>Investor Information<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Our Funds<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Fund search</a>
              <a href="#">Browse our funds</a>
              <a href="#">Income funds</a>
              <a href="#">Growth funds</a>
              <a href="#">Mutusl Funds</a>
              <a href="#">OEIC's</a>
              <a href="#">Investment Trusts</a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Enterprise Investing<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Venture Capital Trusts</a>
              <a href="#">Enterprise Investment Schemes</a>
              <a href="#">Tax investives</a>
              <a href="#">Risk Disclaimer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="row main-menu-rotating-advert">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="simple-carousel">
                    <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic-main-menu" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators main-menu-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main-menu" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main-menu" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main-menu" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="main-menu-slide-1 main-menu-image-item item active">
                          <div class="bottom-text-box">
                            <h4><b>Is this the real life.</b></h4>
                            <p>I say, what about breakfast at Tffanys</p>
                            <p style="font-size: 10px!important;">We will not sell or disseminate your data to any third party.</p>
                            <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-menu-slide-2 main-menu-image-item item">
                          <div class="bottom-text-box">
                            <h4><b>Is this just fantasy.</b></h4>
                            <p>She said "I think I remember the film.."</p>
                            <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-menu-slide-3 main-menu-image-item item">
                          <div class="bottom-text-box">
                            <h4><b>Calling a landslide.</b></h4>
                            <p>Find out how much your pension is worth with our free checker.</p>
                            <p style="font-size: 10px!important;">Terms & conditions apply.</p>
                            <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Fund research</strong></a>
        <ul>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-6">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Search our Funds</div>
              <p><strong>Search our range of available funds, or go to our <a style="display:inline;" href="#">advanced section.</a></strong></p>
              <form action="" class="search-form" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for a stock by name or ticker symbol">
                <p><a style="display:inline;" href="#">Recently searched funds<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 main-menu-column">
              <div class="main-menu-static-1">
                <div class="main-menu-static-text-box">
                  <h4><b>Find out how much your pension is worth.</b></h4>
                  <p>Take a look at my girlfriend, she's the only one I've got.</p>
                  <a href="#">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 main-menu-column"></div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Share prices & stock markets</b></a>
        <ul>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-6">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Search for a stock</div>
              <p><strong>Search ur range of available funds, or go to our <a style="display:inline;" href="#">advanced section.</a></strong></p>
              <form action="" class="search-form" >
                <input type="search" class="form-control" name="funds-search" placeholder="Search for a fund or ISBN..">
                <p><a style="display:inline;" href="#">Recently searched stocks<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Browse our shares<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Leaders & Laggagrds</a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Market News<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Director Dealings</a>
              <a href="#">AIM Funds</a>
              <a href="#">Newspaper roundup</a>
              <a href="#">Financial diary</a>
              <a href="#">Corporate actions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Other investments</div>
              <a href="#">Venture Capital Trusts</a>
              <a href="#">Enterprise Investment Schemes</a>
              <a href="#">Venture Capital Funds</a>
              <a href="#">Tax benefits & sacrifices</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Newsroom</b></a>
        <ul>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12"><div style="font-size:30px !important;" class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Featured news.</div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Header 1</div>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Header 2<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Test Header</div>
              <a href="#">Whatever</a>
              <a href="#"><b></b>Whatever</a>
              <a href="#"><b>Whatever</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-6">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header col-md-12"><a href="#">Header 3 <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <div class="main-menu-column col-md-6">
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Test Header</div>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-menu-column col-md-6">
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Planning & guidence</b></a>
        <ul>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12"><div style="font-size:30px !important;" class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Planning & guidence.</div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Planning for the future</div>
              <a href="#">Planning your future</a>
              <a href="#">Retirement & Savings</a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header"><a href="#">Investor relations<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <a href="#">Share prices</a>
              <a href="#">Invest in our business</a>
              <a href="#">Private Shareholdings</a>
              <a href="#">Become an Investor</a>
              <a href="#">Careers</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-3">
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Retirement & Savings</div>
              <a href="#">Your pension options</a>
              <a href="#">Later Life</a>
              <a href="#">401(K)</a>
              <a href="#">Transfer your pension</a>
              <div class="main-menu-column-header-non-link">Market Watch</div>
              <a href="#">FTSE 100</a>
              <a href="#">FTSE 250</a>
              <a href="#">FTSE 350</a>
              <a href="#">AIM Markets</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-column col-md-6">
              <div class="col-md-12 banner">
                <div class="banner-text col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="banner-caption col-md-6"><p>The value of your investments can go downwards as well as upwards, therefore, you may not get back the amount you initially invested.</p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Pensions & Savings</strong></a>
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul><!--End of Main Menu tag-->
  </div><!--End of navWrapper tag-->
</div><!--End of nav tag-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Use the transition-delay css property

```
div {
-webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
transition-delay: 2s; 
}
```

2) Try adding transform: translateX() to the hover class

```
div:hover {
-ms-transform: translate(50px, 100px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate(50px, 100px); /* Safari */
transform: translate(50px, 100px);
}
```

Hope that helps!